# How do I create a for loop where i = 0

Tags: java, int, boolean

I'm a beginner at java and I'm facing a very basic problem that I just can't seem to figure out. Any insight or feedback will be greatly appreciated. 
My program takes user input of the number of trips a car has undergone, and each odometer reading between each trip then calculates the longest, shortest and average distance traveled between each trip.

So far, it works OK besides when there is a test case where the user inputs 0 number of trips, which should output 0 for all calculations (shortest, longest average) but i get the max integer value for each output (2 billion).

I've tried to create a loop that accepts if the number of trips does = 0, then a message is outputted "there is no trips" however I keep receiving this error:

> TestCar.java:20: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Boolean
>   for (int i = 0; i = carSample.numberOfTrips; i++) {

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.
Here is my code:

```
System.out.print("Input trips: ");  
carSample.numberOfTrips = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i = carSample.numberOfTrips; i++) {
    System.out.print("There are no trips");
    }

    int previous = 0;
    int minimumTrip = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maximumTrip = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    System.out.print("Odometer reading 0: " );
    carSample.odometerReading = input.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < carSample.numberOfTrips; i++) {
    System.out.print("Odometer reading " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    int odometerReading = input.nextInt();
    int currentTrip = odometerReading - previous;
    if (currentTrip > maximumTrip){
        maximumTrip = currentTrip;
        }
    if (currentTrip < minimumTrip){
        minimumTrip = currentTrip;  
    }
    previous = odometerReading;
```

Comment: Use == in for loop condition

Comment: It seems like you should be using an if-statement rather than a for-loop for that first condition of 0 and checking `if (carSample.numberOfTrips == 0)`

Comment: And i think "if" will do your job, "for" is not needed

Comment: I tried using if, however i receive the same error. I'll try == now, didnt think of that!

Comment: ‘i = carSample.numberOfTrips’ in the for loop is assignment. You need == for comparison

Comment: ok == works, however how would i go about breaking or ending the second loop from occuring once the condition carSample.numberOfTrips has been satisfied?

Comment: Use if else - if no trips then print stuff else run the for loop

Comment: if(0== carSample.numberOfTrips) { System.out.print("There are no trips"); return;}

Comment: Return works, cheers for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple matter of branching based on user input. There's no reason to run a `for` loop zero times. Here's the logic behind it (you can write the actual code yourself):

```
if numTrips == 0
    print error message
else
    for numTrips
        blah blah all your logic goes here
    end for
end else
```

Comment: You might want to make the code `if numTrips <= 0` in case your user wants to feed your program wonky input like -1. Get in the habit of assuming users will do something crazy -- it'll save you from heartbreak throughout your career.

Comment: by any chance would you know how to get rid of the .0 at the end of a double/float output when not needed? i keep failing my test cases for an example because the program wants me to have average distance as a double value, e.g 1263.78. Which is an easy fix i just set it to a double variable, however i fail the test case when it is a whole number since i get 100.0 and not just 100. How could i remidy this? cheers.

Comment: @utnicho Look into a Java class called DecimalFormat. In the future, try not to follow up questions in the comments. If you have a new question, just post it as such, and people will be happy to help you. In fact, if you search Stack Overflow for DecimalFormat. you should be able to find a ton of examples.